# app using play game services [error]

Tags: android, google-play-games

I developed a game using the game play service on Android. When I get the signed Generate APK I can log in using the game service but the same Generated signed APK with don't login when I load it into the play store. Why could it be?

Comment: can you elaborate your question please ?

Comment: Seems like there is some different release and debug configurations set in code. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I implemented the android app using Google play game service.
1) https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart
I downloaded and integrated the required library as described in my site.
2) I got google play game apis from https://console.developers.google.com.
3) In my application I can export the signed api and log on to the phones with the game service. I can not log in when I upload the same APK to google play.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the App Signing on the play console, but did not create a linked App credential for your game.  When you are building locally it is using the SHA1 fingerprint of the keystore on your computer, but when you upload the app, it is signed with the keystore in the console?